# Oracle - Splitting full name in parts (first, middle, last)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am writing a procedure, in oracle, and need to split full name into 3 parts, Firstname, Middle name and lastname.

I've done first version, and it help me a little bit, but need some enhancements.

Detailing what I did.

```
  SUBSTR(TRIM(EMPREGADO.ABALPH), 1, instr(TRIM(EMPREGADO.ABALPH), ' ')) "PRIMEIRO NOME",
  SUBSTR(TRIM(EMPREGADO.ABALPH), instr(TRIM(EMPREGADO.ABALPH), ' ') + 1,instr(TRIM(EMPREGADO.ABALPH), ' ', 1, 2) - instr(TRIM(EMPREGADO.ABALPH), ' ')) "NOME DO MEIO",
  SUBSTR(TRIM(EMPREGADO.ABALPH), instr(TRIM(EMPREGADO.ABALPH), ' ', -1)) "ULTIMO  NOME"
```

The result is satisfactory but not optimal.

Example with the code below.

On the column "Empregado.ABALPH", I have the name "PRISCILA DE OLIVEIRA TORRES". After running the select, the result is as follows

**FirstName = Priscila**

**MiddleName = De**

**LastName = TORRES**

So, that it is as expected, need to include the middle name, all names that are between the firstname and lastname. Somthing like that:

**FirstName = Priscila**

**MiddleName = De Oliveira**

**LastName = TORRES**

Or could be:

**FirstName = Priscila**

**MiddleName = D. O.**

**LastName = TORRES**

How should I optimize my select, so that the result be as described?

Important point: The middle name may have sometimes more than one name, like "CARLOS EDUARDO FERREIRA DA SILVA"

Tks a lot.

Comment: Look at using regular expressions instead.

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Well, as OldProgrammer suggested, I would build a regular expression but first you would have to define rules for how to recognize first and last names.  For instance, in your last example, a last name could be a single word, optionally preceded by "DA".  What other variations could there be?  Do the same for first names for whatever languages could be in your database.  Then assume everything else in between goes into the middle name? Once you have the rules defined you can get started on a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this:

```
SQL> with empregado as (
  2  select 'PRISCILA DE OLIVEIRA TORRES' ABALPH from dual union all
  3  select 'PRISCILA OLIVEIRA TORRES' from dual union all
  4  select 'PRISCILA DA SILVA TORRES' from dual union all
  5  select 'PRISCILA DA SILVA TORRES' from dual union all
  6  select 'CARLOS EDUARDO FERREIRA DA SILVA' from dual union all
  7  select 'CARLOS EDUARDO DOS SANTOS FERREIRA DA SILVA' from dual
  8  )-- end of sample data
  9  select abalph,
 10         clean_name,
 11         regexp_substr(clean_name, '^[[:alpha:]]+') "PRIMEIRO NOME",
 12         regexp_replace(regexp_replace(clean_name, '^[[:alpha:]]+[ ]+'), '[ ]+[[:alpha:]]+$') "NOME DO MEIO",
 13         regexp_substr(clean_name, '[[:alpha:]]+$') "ULTIMO NOME"
 14    from (select regexp_replace(abalph, '( DA | DO | DAS | DOS | DE )', ' ') clean_name,
 15                 abalph
 16            from empregado) e;
ABALPH                                      CLEAN_NAME                                         PRIMEIRO NOME        NOME DO MEIO                             ULTIMO NOME
------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------------------
PRISCILA DE OLIVEIRA TORRES                 PRISCILA OLIVEIRA TORRES                           PRISCILA             OLIVEIRA                                 TORRES
PRISCILA OLIVEIRA TORRES                    PRISCILA OLIVEIRA TORRES                           PRISCILA             OLIVEIRA                                 TORRES
PRISCILA DA SILVA TORRES                    PRISCILA SILVA TORRES                              PRISCILA             SILVA                                    TORRES
PRISCILA DA SILVA TORRES                    PRISCILA SILVA TORRES                              PRISCILA             SILVA                                    TORRES
CARLOS EDUARDO FERREIRA DA SILVA            CARLOS EDUARDO FERREIRA SILVA                      CARLOS               EDUARDO FERREIRA                         SILVA
CARLOS EDUARDO DOS SANTOS FERREIRA DA SILVA CARLOS EDUARDO SANTOS FERREIRA SILVA               CARLOS               EDUARDO SANTOS FERREIRA                  SILVA
6 rows selected
```

I guessed a bit of the rules, but you can remove the "clean name" column and work with the "DA DO DE etc" if you want to. Just thought it would help in case you need to remove them at some point.